# powertop keeps telling me to turn off the same thing, over and over

Tags: power, battery

I am running an ubuntu lucid laptop on battery. I want to make my power last as long as possible. Aswell as the normal things like turn down screen brightness, and turn off wifi, I'm using `powertop`. It will sometimes tell me things, e.g.:

```
Suggestion: Enable USB autosuspend by pressing the U key
```

OK, I press the U key to do that.

However a few minutes later it will give me the same suggestion, it's as if it never enabled USB autosuspend the first time.

It does this for other things aswell, not just USB autosuspend. e.g. it'll give me this message frequently:

```
An audio device is active 100.0% of the time:
hwC0D1 LSI ID 1040 

 Q - Quit   R - Refresh   A - Turn HD audio powersave on
```

Is there anything I can do to make these choices 'stick'? Or do I have some unfortunatle hardware that won't obey linux? (If so, is there any way to confirm this?)

Comment: superuser.com ?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of devices do you have plugged into the usb ports?   One or more of those devices may not like the 'autosuspend' setting and forces it back on... which would cause powertop to re-suggest it.